# How to create decodable of nested array in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire, decodable

Background: I'm using swift Alamofire@5.6.2 and I need to parse json data

```
AF.request("https://xxx.json").validate().responseDecodable(of: Decodable)
```

The data looks like:

```json
[
   [
       "a",
       123,
       1.0,
   ],
   [
       "b",
       456,
       2.0,
   ],
]
```

My code (this is the wrong way):

```swift
struct Item: Codable {
   var name: String
}

...responseDecodable(of: [Item].self)
```

Should I use enum instead? I read some similar answers but they all have keys at some point, my data is pure array without keys.

Comment: This is extremely unpractical JSON. Basically you can decode nested arrays directly without creating structs, but the inner array must be homogenous (one type). Yours is not, so you have to create a struct, decode the array as (nested)unkeyedContainer and determine the different types *manually*.

Comment: @vadian thanks, I will change the json structure. I'm new to swift, for now I'm curious about how to did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the types are always the same in the same order this is a simple example how to decode the inner array, the struct member names are arbitrary

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let someInt: Int
    let someDouble: Double
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        name = try container.decode(String.self)
        someInt = try container.decode(Int.self)
        someDouble = try container.decode(Double.self)
    }
}
```

and decode `[Item].self`